# Open Form1 as new instance after successful operations on Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having two forms as Form1 and Form2 on Form1 button click I am opening the form2 as follows

```
private Form2 form2;
this.Hide();
form2.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

I have a back button and submit button on Form2 when I click on Back this is how I am showing Form1

```
this.Hide();
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

But when I submit the form I need to load the Form1 with new instance, this is what I tried but Form1 is showing multiple times

```
if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("Installation was done", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information))
{
   Form f1 = new Form ();
   f1.Show();
   this.Close();
}
```

When I execute my application this is how it looks after entering data to my textbox

[image]

After clicking on button1 it will show the data in Form2 if user wants to modify data he can come back if he clicks on submit I would like to have the new instance of Form1

[image]

Comment: First you need to close the existing `Form1`

Comment: Is form1 show by Show() or by ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is after you open form 2 do something like

```
    Form1.close();
```

and then when you are done with the operation:

```
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(); 
    form1.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
```

Ok if you want to save the data from form1 then i would either fave the data as a file that you could retrieve when ever of pass all of the variables you want to save into Form2 and then save them there. also instead of using a new form 1 you could use the existing one and reset any values that you want to reset.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But when I click on back I don't want to lose form1 data

Comment: why do you want anew instance? that would better help me to understand the nature of you problem.

Comment: Attached a new image please look and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I tried, on your Form1 button click event write the following

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2.ShowData(textBox1.Text);
    form2.ShowDialog(this);    
}
```

In your Form2 submit click have the following code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Owner.Hide();
   this.Owner = new Form1(this);
   this.Hide();
   this.Owner.Show();
}
```